# HTML CSS responsive div under certain pixels

Tags: css

I am trying to make 1 of my pages responsive for mobile screens, I created 2 arrows and text just above the body div.
Now i only want these arrows and text to appear when screen is below 800px.
How can i do that ?
i tried this: 
{display none only when screen above 800px}
not working!

```
 @media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
      .box11 .arrowRight {
      text-align: center;
      color: #204486;
      padding: 10px;
      margin: 10px;
display:none;

    }
    .box11 .arrowP {
     text-align: center;
      color: #204486;
      padding: 10px;
      margin: 10px;
display:none;
    }
```

Comment: you are missing a closing brace.

Comment: also i need to replace max width with min, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Missed closing brace and changed max-width to min-width, thanks